# ScrollBar not working fine in IE

Tags: angular

Hi I have a vertical scrollbar in addUSer Page. But When I am selection multiple values in dropdown page length is getting increased and scrollbar is not coming proper. In chrome and Mozilla its working fine. This issue is coming only in IE. Submit button is not visible to me as i am not able to scroll scrollBar down.
This is the CSS for scrollbar

```
    .scrollable {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;

     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the css seems to have fixed it:

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you can see this link will be help you https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/angular.html